# What is the proper Hibernate session timeout value to avoid deadlock?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, timeout, deadlock

Our Postgresql application is getting Hibernate error: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: deadlock detected.  One of the ways recommended to deal with this problem is setting transaction timeout
(Hibernate Reference Documentation) :

```
sess.getTransaction().setTimeout(3)
```

How this value of 3 seconds is defined?

Comment: It could be a magic number. But, to prevent deadlocks, you have to maintain the consistent order in which you call the query/saving the data.

Comment: Who recommended this way of dealing with the problem?  It makes no sense.  If you had undetected deadlocks this might be a viable last-ditch effort to avoid them.  But your deadlocks are already being detected, so why invent a much worse say of detecting them?

Comment: I need to put a fix quickly. I plan to put a better handling after incoming release and switching to an updated Hibernate version

Answer (score 0):

If your queries are deadlocking, look into why they are deadlocking and fix that. The error message in the PostgreSQL server error log tells you about the transactions that deadlocked. If that alone isn't enough, set `log_statement = 'all'`, add a `log_line_prefix` to identify transactions or use csv logging, and analyze the log files to see what's happening.

If you're stuck you can hand-recreate the deadlock and take a look at `pg_locks` for additional information about what's going on; see [the lock monitoring wiki article](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring).

If the deadlock detection timeout is too long for you, lower PostgreSQL's deadlock detection timeout, don't add statement timeout hacks in the application. See [the documentation on lock management](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-locks.html).